# Bash: Merge foldername from variable with filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, command-substitution

First I write a configfile with all my parameters like this

```
path="/home/test/"
```

I name it `test.conf`.

Then I write a shell script with this content, name it `test`, and make it executable with `chmod +x`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#read the config file
. /home/test/test.conf

#cat the file /home/test/test
cat `$path`test #This line is the problem
```

I get this output

```
./test/test: line 3: /home/test/: Is a directory
cat: test: No such file or directory
```

What I would like is that it shows me the content of the file `/home/test/test`.

How do I write this script correctly, so that it doesn't make a new line after the file path?

Comment: You should use double quotes (`"$path"`), not backquotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

``` `` ``` and `$()` is used for command execution, not for substituting it for variable content. So bash tries to execute varaible meaning in ``` `` ``` and returns the error that it is a directory.

Just write `cat ${path}test` and it will work in the way you want.

For more information read about [bash variables](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) and [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).